# Add Desktop Environment to minimal install only cli?

Tags: system-installation, desktop-environments, ubuntu-minimal

I tried installing from a usb with a full image, but was having issues. So, I tried a minimal install and selected to include ubuntu desktop, but upon first boot it brought me to an extremely bare bones command line interface. 
This is a quote from the canonical minimal page at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD:

"To install, boot your computer from the the mini iso and select "Install" at the prompt. You can then follow the instructions from the text-based installer. On the software selection screen, you can select from a number of collections of software such as different desktop environments (kde, xfce, etc), a multitude of different servers, multimedia creation tools, media center (mythbuntu), etc. You can also select "Manual package selection" which will take you to aptitude. You may also select nothing and just continue to finish the installation. If you selected nothing, upon reboot you will arrive at a cli prompt; from here you can fully customize your new system."

I'm going to go ahead and try re-installing it again, but does anybody know how I could install a desktop environment? Not just a desktop environment, but the current standard Ubuntu environment?

Comment: The 'current' desktop environment for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and 19.04 is GNOME  https://www.gnome.org/ . The desktop environment for 16.04 LTS is Unity https://github.com/ubports/unity8/blob/xenial/README.md Since all three versions of Ubuntu are supported, the choice depends on which version of Ubuntu you use. Other DEs are also supported; see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors .  Please click [edit] and tell us which you want. Please do not click Add Comment; instead use [edit].

Comment: It should have installed the desktop but sometimes you have to run `tasksel` after you do the initial install. Also, make sure to unplug the USB device before the system reboots so that the system doesn't reboot to the pendrive instead of the system. Another problem is that sometimes grub accidentally gets installed to the USB stick instead of the main drive but that doesn't sound like your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you install a desktop on a minimum install or headless server.

First, run the following commands to install `tasksel`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tasksel
```

Run the following command to install a desktop:

```
sudo tasksel
```

Then, you can select your desired desktop environment. Choosing the "Ubuntu desktop" will install Gnome Shell which is the standard Ubuntu desktop on 18.04+. **Do not select any of the "live cd" options**.

Use the <kbd>space bar</kbd> to select or deselect a desktop and then use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to select "OK" and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to install.

You can always run the `sudo tasksel` command in the future if you want to install another desktop environment.

**NOTE:** [because of a bug in tasksel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/1779645), DO NOT use tasksel to uninstall packages. ONLY use tasksel to install.

Comment: +1; It works to install the desktop environment directly too, with `sudo apt update` followed by one of the following command lines, `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`; `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop`; `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop`; ... `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @sudodus Yes, you can install using one of those commands but `tasksel` is how the tutorials usually explain how to do it. Also, `tasksel` lists other package collections that are commonly installed or needed with a basic install like LAMP, multimedia packages, games, etc.

Comment: That's right, it is a good idea to learn using `tasksel` :-)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of steps here:

1. ensure you're using the right desktop environment:

```
ls /usr/bin/*session
```

this should list gnome-desktop or something like that.

2. You should be able to run the desktop by this:

```
startx
```

3. If that doesn't work restart the daemon like this:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart
```

and then try step 2 again.